# Calculating average amount outstanding for customers live in consecutive months in a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that sums the $ amount of money that a customer has in their account during a particular month. If the customer has no money, the amount is simply 0. The dataframe looks like the below:

```
Customer    A       B       C       D       E        F   
11/30/2015  0       1,000   0       0       5,000    0   
12/31/2015  2,133   1,000   0       3,000   5,000    2,000
1/31/2016   2,133   0       0       3,000   5,000    2,000
2/29/2016   2,133   2,000   4,000   3,000   5,000    2,000
3/31/2016   2,133   2,000   4,000   0       10,000   2,000
4/30/2016   0       2,000   4,000   0       10,000   0   
5/31/2016   0       2,000   4,000   0       10,000   0
```

When a customer is live, they they have a nominal amount in their account for the particular month. Similarly, if they are live in the following month (or any month) they have a nominal amount in for that month also.

I want to add a column at the end of the dataframe which calculates the average amount in customers accounts during the same month, but only for customers that were also live during the previous month

I am trying to do some analysis on customer retention, and therefore I need the average amount outstanding to customers during this month, for customers that were live in the previous month also.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
Customer    A       B       C       D       E        F       Avg Outstanding consecutive Months
11/30/2015  0       1,000   0       0       5,000    0       0
12/31/2015  2,000   1,000   0       3,000   5,000    2,000   3,000
1/31/2016   2,000   0       0       3,000   5,000    2,000   3,000
2/29/2016   2,000   2,000   4,000   3,000   5,000    2,000   3,000
3/31/2016   2,000   2,000   4,000   0       10,000   2,000   4,000
4/30/2016   0       2,000   4,000   0       10,000   0       5,333
5/31/2016   0       2,000   4,000   0       10,000   0       5,333
```

Comment: Is the `Customer` column the index of your dataframe?

Comment: The date column on the left is the index. The Customer just refers to the label of the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first transform your data to python readable form by removing ',' and converting to integers

```
df.set_index(['Customer'],inplace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(' '.join,axis=1).str.replace(',', '').str.split(expand=False).tolist(),columns=df.columns,index=df.index).astype(int)
```

Now check the condition whether the value is equal to 0 and shift the dataframe,now you can take negative of boolean dataframe which will only have live examples

```
df  = df[~df.eq(0).shift().fillna(False)].fillna(0)
```

Out:
masked Dataframe

```
             A    B    C      D    E     F
Customer                        
11/30/2015  0.0 1000.0  0.0 0.0 5000    0.0
12/31/2015  0.0 1000.0  0.0 0.0 5000    0.0
1/31/2016   2133.0  0.0 0.0 3000.0  5000    2000.0
2/29/2016   2133.0  0.0 0.0 3000.0  5000    2000.0
3/31/2016   2133.0  2000.0  4000.0  0.0 10000   2000.0
4/30/2016   0.0 2000.0  4000.0  0.0 10000   0.0
5/31/2016   0.0 2000.0  4000.0  0.0 10000   0.0
```

Now you can take mean out of dataframe by axis one with only live values

```
df1['Avg Outstanding'] = df1.apply(lambda x: sum(x)/x.ne(0).sum(),1).astype(int)
```

Out:

```
              A       B       C     D        E      F   Avg Outstanding
Customer                            
11/30/2015  0.0     1000.0   0.0    0.0     5000    0.0     3000
12/31/2015  0.0     1000.0   0.0    0.0     5000    0.0     3000
1/31/2016   2133.0  0.0      0.0   3000.0   5000   2000.0   3033
2/29/2016   2133.0  0.0      0.0   3000.0   5000   2000.0   3033
3/31/2016   2133.0  2000.0  4000.0  0.0    10000   2000.0   4026
4/30/2016   0.0     2000.0  4000.0  0.0    10000    0.0     5333
5/31/2016   0.0     2000.0  4000.0  0.0    10000    0.0     5333
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

It's nearly correct, but I need to only calculate the average of the values that were also live in the month previous. 

I.e. for 1/31/2016, I would only calculate the average for column E, since it is the only column that was live in 12/31/2015.

Similarly, for 2/29/2016, I would calculate the average of columns A,D,E,F because each had a value for 1/31/2016

Comment: but your expected output is just excluding one day prior 0 values. i think you are seeing the masked dataframe @BriainODonnell

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @nagaKiran.

The expected output for 1/31/2016 is 5000 for example. In your answer your output for the same row is 3033